# The Lines Drawn on the ScrollView is not Scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, drawrect

In My Application I've subclassed the `UIScrollView` and draw horizontal Lines in the `drawRect` method

I set the height the `ContentSize` greater than the height of `scrollView`. I use below method to draw the lines

But my problem is that the lines I have drawn is not scrolling with View.

```
-(id)initWithFFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
  _gap=36;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    int end=0;
    NSLog(@"called");
    int x=self.frame.size.width;
    while (end<self.contentSize.height) {
        CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, end);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, end);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        end=end+_gap;
    }
}
```

I can notice the scroller moving up and down when scrolling but the lines are not moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that those lines are part of the `UIScrollView` and not of it's content.

You need to create a new `UIView` subclass, draw the content there, and add this to your `UIScrollView`

Comment: I don't think that's true--when scroll view scrolls it's bounds changes too so drawing should be fine. I think the problem is that setNeedsDisplay needs to be called whenever the view is scrolled. however: that will probably give bad performance. your answer is the right way.